# Sign envelope through REST API?

Tags: rest, docusignapi

Is it possible to actually sign an envelope through the REST API? Not just get an embedded signer Url token, but actually sign the envelope?

Comment: Need more details - can't figure out what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible to automate the signing of documents through the api - that's the one part that the human still has to perform.  I'm not sure if you will ever be able to sign through the api either - think about things like authentication (such as RSA ID Checks, phone auth, etc.) and also if the user starts reading the document and decides to decline to sign the envelope.  There are some things that the human still has do such as these things.